# Add a type function to a Swift unit test target

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xctest

How does one go about making a type function (defined in an extension) visible to a test target in Swift?  If I have the following extension in my project:

```
extension NSData {
    class func XOR(inputData: NSData, withKey key: NSData) -> NSData {            
        ...            
        return NSData(bytes: output.baseAddress, length: inputData.length)
    }
}
```

the `XOR` function is visible to the the main project however not in the test target.  I also have `@testable import MyModule` in my test file.  (As an aside, interestingly *variables* which are added in the extension are visible to the test target).

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways (that I can recall) of making the function visible from within your test target.

1. Add your test target to the target membership of the file containing the extension.
2. Promote the function from `internal` (which is implicitly set by omitting an access modifier) to `public`.
3. Upgrade to the Xcode 7 beta and use Swift 2's new `@testable` attribute to import your module. Doing so will implicitly promote your `internal` variables/methods/etc to `public` to make them visible from within the tests target.

```
@testable import MyModule
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  I have the `@testable import` already and it's still unable to see the type function

Comment: @NSTJ Sorry for the delay. I'm unable to replicate the problem, and am not sure why you might be seeing this behavior.

Comment: I think I must be doing something silly for this to be happening.  I'll post some code when I have 2s to get to the bottom of this.  Appreciate your response.